# Android : How to do sync data automatically

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-syncadapter, android-async-http

In my application I will get large amount of data from the server. I want to sync all the data by automatically with the device. Even when my app is not in use, I want to sync the data.

Right now I have done that by using AsyncTask. But it is taking long time to get the data.

This is the code I have written in my MainActivity.

```
public class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

      private Context mCon;
    public UpdateTask(Context con)
    {
        mCon = con;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute(); 
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... nope) {
        try {
            // Set a time to simulate a long update process.

            //Thread.sleep(4000);
            getData();
            getProjectInit();
            getProjRequirements();
            return null;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void nope) {

    }

public void getProjRequirements()
    {
        projList = Project.listAll();
        for(int i = 0;i<projList.size();i++)
        {
            proj = projList.get(i);
        RequestParams params2 = new RequestParams();
        AsyncClientHandler.get("projectMaster/Getdetails/"+proj.p_id, params2, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    Throwable error, String content) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, error, content);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    String content) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, content);
                //Log.i("projectid",proj.p_id.toString());
                try
                {
                    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(content);
                    Log.i("projreq_content",content.toString());
                    JSONArray projectrequirement = data.getJSONArray("requirements");
                    Log.i("requirement",projectrequirement.toString());
                    for(int i=0;i<projectrequirement.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject projrequire = projectrequirement.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("projreqwqwq",projrequire.toString());
                        prrq = ProjectRequirements.getProjectRequirementsByPidRid(getValue(projrequire,"id"),getValue(projrequire,"pid"),getValue(projrequire,"sid"));

                         if(prrq==null)
                              prrq=new ProjectRequirements();
                        prrq.pr_id=getValue(projrequire,"id");
                        prrq.pid=getValue(projrequire,"pid");
                        prrq.srid=getValue(projrequire,"srid");
                        prrq.sid=getValue(projrequire,"sid");
                        prrq.rid=getValue(projrequire,"rid");
                        prrq.estimated_value=getValue(projrequire,"estimated_value");
                        prrq.expected_close_date=getValue(projrequire, "expected_close_date");
                        prrq.others=getValue(projrequire,"others");
                        prrq.requirement_id=getValue(projrequire,"requirement_id");
                        prrq.name=getValue(projrequire,"name");
                        prrq.save();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }

        });
        }
    }

}
```

I have given the getProjectRequirements() code.

But this will take long time to display it in other fragments.

For this scenario what can i prefer and could someone give me a example or any tutorial?

I have scene SyncAdapter in android developer website. But it's looking quite difficult for me.

Could someone provide me some easy example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are syncing periodically and the application does not need the
data immediately I would use an IntentService.

To make it run periodically I would register it with the AlarmManager. If you do that it will run even if the application is not active.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html